# How to decrypt the message in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, encryption

The message was encrypted by Java Code below:

```
 public String encrypt(String value) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKeyFactory  keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    String salt="";
    SecretKey sk = keyFactory.generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(salt.getBytes()));
    encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk);
    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encryptCipher.doFinal(value.getBytes())));
}
```

I did some research and found mysql has `DES_DECRPT` and  `FROM_BASE64` function 
I try to decrypt the `message=BCgS49ZhlEfiEhvxnR0guX06XBmv7Q1W`  by

```
Select DES_DECRIPT(FROM_BASE64(message), '')
```

But return unreadable string.

I am not sure if it is right way to decrypt, can anyone help me?

Comment: `new DESKeySpec("".getBytes())` throws a `InvalidKeyException`

Comment: Have you considered providing the encryption key to the decryption function?

Comment: @wero,  You are right, the salt should not be empty, I am back to Java code  look for the exact salt.

Answer (score 2):

**MySQL DES_DECRYPT()**

function decrypts an encrypted string and returns the original string.

*Syntax*

```
DES_DECRYPT(crypt_str, [key_str]);
```

*Arguments*

- crypt_str   =    An encrypted string.
- key_str  =  String to decrypt crypt_str.

Example :

```
SELECT DES_ENCRYPT('mytext','mypassward');
SELECT DES_DECRYPT(DES_ENCRYPT('mytext','mypassward'),'mypassward');
```